# Scan All private subnets with NMAP

Tags: network-scanners, nmap

I have a managed switch on my network but I don't remember the subnet.

How can I scan all the private network without changing my ip address : 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16

Thanks for advices

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a security question - the nmap manual will give you the answer

Comment: Or, read this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/10678/485

Comment: IMHO it's a security question because some devices can be connected to the network and on another ip range. This can have a security impact.

Comment: that does not make it a security question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are really looking for the tool [netdiscover](http://web.archive.org/web/20160413160027/http://nixgeneration.com/~jaime/netdiscover).

Netdiscover works by sending and listening for ARP packets. (active and passive mode). Since it is ARP, its limitation is that it only work on the same LAN (layer 2) - you cannot traverse gateway's.

You do not have to change the ip address on your interface with this tool.

Comment: seems like the URL changed to: https://sourceforge.net/projects/netdiscover/

Comment: Latest URL is here: https://github.com/netdiscover-scanner/netdiscover